# Remote dataannotation not triggering in front-end with kendo controls

Tags: kendo-ui, data-annotations

I have two controls Speed and Speed unit. Speed is a numeric textbox and Speed unit is a dropdown.
[image]

The speed field is required if speed unit is filled in and visa versa.

To achieve this validation I'm using the [remote data annotation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#remote-attribute). However in the front-end the validation is not triggering.

My viewmodel:

```
[AbpDisplayName(OE_TenantConsts.LocalizationSourceName, "idb_Incident.Speed")]
[Range(0.0, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a value of {1} or more")]
[Remote(action: "VerifySpeedAndUnit", controller: "Event", AdditionalFields = nameof(SpeedUnitId))]
public decimal? Speed { get; set; }

[AbpDisplayName(OE_TenantConsts.LocalizationSourceName, "idb_Incident.SpeedUnitId")]
[Remote(action: "VerifySpeedAndUnit", controller: "Event", AdditionalFields = nameof(Speed))] 
public int? SpeedUnitId { get; set; }
```

My controller (event controller -> VerifySpeedAndUnit):

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult VerifySpeedAndUnit(decimal? speed, int? speedUnitId)
{
    if ((speed.HasValue && speedUnitId == DropdownConstants.DefaultSelectedSpeedUnitId) || (speed.HasValue && speedUnitId == null))
    {
        return Json("When entering a speed, you need to select the speed scale as well.");
    }

    if (speedUnitId != DropdownConstants.DefaultSelectedSpeedUnitId && speed.HasValue && speedUnitId != null)
    {
        return Json("When selecting a speed scale, you need to enter a speed value as well.");
    }

    return Json(true);
}
```

My speed kendo control :

```
                    <div class="mb-5 col-md-6 idb_Incident_Speed">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Speed, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-12" })
                        <div class="col-12">

                            <kendo-numerictextbox deferred="true" for="Speed"
                                              format="#.##"
                                              min="0"
                                              name="Speed"
                                              decimals="2"
                                              placeholder="Enter Speed at time of Incident">
                            </kendo-numerictextbox>

                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Speed, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

If I inspect the html of the form field I can see the properties are being set. But nothing happens:
[image]
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't seem like this is supported out of the box. You have to write some custom jquery to get it to work:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("FormPost","Home",FormMethod.Post,new {id="myForm"}))
{
    <div class="mb-5 col-md-6 idb_Incident_Speed">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Speed, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-12" })
        <div class="col-12">

            <kendo-numerictextbox deferred="true" for="Speed"
                                format="#.##"
                                min="0"
                                name="Speed"
                                decimals="2"
                                placeholder="Enter Speed at time of Incident">
            </kendo-numerictextbox>

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Speed, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    @(Html.Kendo().Button()
        .Name("btn")
        .Content("Submit")
        .HtmlAttributes(new {type="submit"})
    )

}
@Html.Kendo().DeferredScripts()

<script>
   $(document).ready( function () {
        var validator = $("#myForm").kendoValidator({
            rules: {
                remote: function (input) {
                    if (input.val() == "" || !input.attr("data-val-remote-url")) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    if (input.attr("data-val-remote-recieved")) {
                        input.attr("data-val-remote-recieved", "");
                        return !(input.attr("data-val-remote"));
                    }

                    var url = input.attr("data-val-remote-url");
                    var postData = {};
                    postData[input.attr("data-val-remote-additionalfields").split(".")[1]] = input.val();

                    var validator = this;
                    var currentInput = input;
                    input.attr("data-val-remote-requested", true);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        type: "POST",
                        data: JSON.stringify(postData),
                        dataType: "json",
                        traditional: true,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data == true) {
                                input.attr("data-val-remote", "");
                            }
                            else {
                                input.attr("data-val-remote", data);
                            }
                            input.attr("data-val-remote-recieved", true);
                            validator.validateInput(currentInput);

                        },
                        error: function () {
                            input.attr("data-val-remote-recieved", true);
                            validator.validateInput(currentInput);
                        }
                    });
                    return true;
                }
            },
            messages: {
                remote: function (input) {
                    return input.attr("data-val-remote");
                }
            }
        }).getKendoValidator();

        $("#btn").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault()
            if(!validator.validate()){
                //submit form
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

Special thanks to telerik support for the code sample.